# Start a loop from 1

Tags: ruby, loops

I recently came upon the scary idea that `Integer.count` loops in Ruby start from `0` and go to `n-1` while playing with the Facebook Engineering puzzlers. I did the dirty fix of adding one to the block variable in the beginning so that it would start at one instead.

Is there a prettier way?

Example:

```
10.times do |n|
    n += 1
    puts n
end #=> 012345789
```

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Ruby supports a number of ways of counting and looping:

```
1.upto(10) do |i|
  puts i
end

>> 1.upto(10) do |i|
 >     puts i
|    end #=> 1
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

There's also `step` instead of `upto` which allows you to increment by a step value:

```
>> 1.step(10,2) { |i| puts i } #=> 1
1
3
5
7
9
```

Answer (score 30):

You could use a [range](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Range.html):

```
(1..10).each { |i| puts i }
```

Ranges give you full control over the starting and ending indexes (as long as you want to go from a lower value to a higher value).

Answer (score 10):

Try

```
(1..10).each do |i|
 #  ... i goes from 1 to 10
end
```

instead.  It is also easier to read when the value of `i` matters.

Answer (score 4):

Old, but this might be something somebody's lookin for..

```
5.times.with_index(100){|i, idx| p i, idx};nil
#=>
    0
    100
    1
    101
    2
    102
    3
    103
    4
    104
```

Answer (score 2):

There is of course the `while`-loop:

```
i = 1
while i<=10 do
  print "#{i} "
  i += 1
end
# Outputs: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```